# WGET - how to download embedded pdf's that have a download button from a text file URL list? Is it possible?

Tags: linux, pdf, web-scraping, wget

Happy New Years!

I wanted to see if anybody has ever successfully downloaded embedded pdf file's from multiple url's contained in a .txt file for a website?

For instance;

I tried several combinations of wget -i urlist.txt (which downloads all the html files perfectly); however it doesn't also grab each html file's embedded .pdf?xxxxx <---- slug on the end of the .pdf?*

The exact example of this obstacle is the following:

This dataset I have placed all 2 pages of links into a url.txt:

[https://law.justia.com/cases/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/2014/](http://%20https://law.justia.com/cases/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/2014/)

1 example URL within this dataset:

https://law.justia.com/cases/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/2014/70147-9.html

The embedded pdf link is the following:

https://cases.justia.com/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/2014-70147-9.pdf?ts=1419887549

The .pdf files are actually "2014-70147-9.pdf?ts=1419887549" .pdf?ts=xxxxxxxxxx

each one is different.

The URL list contains 795 links. Does anyone have a successful method to download every .html in my urls.txt while also downloading the .pdfxxxxxxxxxxxxxx file's also to go with the .html's ?

Thank you!

~ Brandon

Comment: Just use Selenium's Python bindings. It's fun and you'll learn the basics of at least two things.

Comment: Roadowl; Thank you for suggesting to research Selenium Python Bindings. I believe I read it's a headless browser. I will look into it's features. Thank's for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following:

```
wget --level 1 --recursive --span-hosts --accept-regex 'https://law.justia.com/cases/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/2014/.*html|https://cases.justia.com/washington/court-of-appeals-division-i/.*.pdf.*' --input-file=urllist.txt
```

Details about the options `--level`, `--recursive`, `--span-hosts`, `--accept-regex`, and `--input-file` can be found in wget documentation at https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/index.html.

You will also need to know how regular expressions work. You can start at https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html

Comment: pii_ke: This works fantastic! Thank you so very much! I will be learning more indepth on each of those switches. I like how you included --accept-regex and used the custom regex to capture asterix. This has taught me quite a bit so far. I am guessing that --span-hosts allows cross sub domain wget's. I have another question on wget for a different domain; is it appropriate to ask here since you are obviously the expert or, should I open another question when time alots?

Comment: @BrandonEVT I'm not that much of an expert, I had to try many times while reading the Wget Manual. You are welcome to add new questions for other queries there are many people on stackoverflow who can help you. If you've found this answer useful please mark it accepted by clicking on the tick mark beside it.

Comment: again thank you. Just clicked the mark for accepted. Thanks for teaching more of stackoverflow. I will make another question then. Have a great new year!

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for a web-scraper. Be careful to not break any rules if you ever use one.

You could also process the content you have received through `wget` using some string manipulation in a bash script.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion on this. Do you know if bs4 in python has the sufficient capabilities to extract embedded PDF's; rather than WGET?

Comment: The reference to court decisions is ludicrous.

Comment: Removed "ludicrous" comment on content in links from question.